# Cannot access created sharepoint site from client machine other than server machine

Tags: sharepoint-2013, spsite

SharePoint2013: I have installed SP2013 in windowsserver2008, I have chosen standalone server while configuring the server. I have created a toplevel site using Central Admin with Admin permissions. I opened the newly created site in the browser successfully. But I cannot connect this site from another machine using browser, i can able to open the site in the same installed server not in another machine using a browser. Can you please suggest me how can I share the created site to users to get work around.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you can't connect, does that mean you get a 404 or that it doesn't allow you log in?

Comment: Have you tried accesssing the server using the IP address instead of the servername? If you can access using the IP address, then you should check and make sure that DNS has the correct info for the server.